# Create a new configuration for Visual Studio Project from command line

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, wix

I want to create a configuration for a Visual Studio projectfrom command line in order to automate my release process. Typically you would go into Visual Studio, create a new configuration, select in the dropdown menu which build to copy from (in my case, this would be Release) and select the platforms. I want to do the same from command line.

I have tried the following:
`MSBuild <mysolution>.sln -p:Configuration=<newconfigname>`

But I get MSB4126 error, telling me that the configuration is not valid. I have also read the documentation on MSBuild, but it does not say anything about this. I am not even sure that this can be achieved using MSBuild. I am using Wix Installer in order to compile a .msi, and that works flawlessly, but it's building the Release configuration, instead of the one I want to build (custom release).

Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by modifying some files.

You need to modify your **.sln** file to add your release type:

```
NewRelease|Any CPU = NewRelease|Any CPU
NewRelease|ARM = NewRelease|ARM
NewRelease|x64 = NewRelease|x64
NewRelease|x86 = NewRelease|x86
```

If you have submodules, add them as well. Create a new configuration in Visual Studio if you have doubts of what you need to add, and copy-paste from the configuration you created with Visual Studio, changing just the name of the configuration where needed.

You need to modify your **.csproj** file of the main project (not the WixInstaller one), for example:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'NewRelease|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>bin\NewRelease\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And, then again, if you have submodules, you have to modify every **.csproj** file to include your new release (copy from the other releases).

Finally, compile it with:
`MSBuild <yourmainproject>.csproj -p:Configuration=NewRelease`.